# Convert non-ASCII/UTF-8 characters into LaTeX codes

Tags: perl, latex, entity

We have to convert non-ASCII, UTF-8, or named entity characters into LaTeX codes. Now we are using non-ASCII to Unicode, then Unicode to LaTeX/entity using a Perl script.

For example:

```
 &oacute; --> \'{o}
 &#x000F3; --> \'{o}
 ó --> \'{o}
```

Is there any direct conversion from non-ASCII, or UTF-8 to LaTeX codes in Perl program/script?

Comment: Your terms are very vague. UTF-8 is non-ASCII, and Unicode isn't an encoding at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is very straightforward using the [`XML::Entities`](https://metacpan.org/pod/XML::Entities) module to decode the entities, and the [`LaTeX::Encode`](https://metacpan.org/pod/LaTeX::Encode) module to re-encode them as LaTeX

Note that I've explicitly created an alias `xml_decode` for the decoding function, as the exported name is just `decode`, which is far too imprecise

```
use utf8;
use strict;
use warnings 'all';
use feature 'say';

use XML::Entities ();
use LaTeX::Encode 'latex_encode';
*xml_decode = \&XML::Entities::decode;

for my $s ( '&oacute;', '&#x000F3;', 'ó' ) {
    my $reencoded = latex_encode(xml_decode('all', $s));
    say $reencoded;
}
```

#### output

```
{\'o}
{\'o}
{\'o}
```

Comment: Another diamond on your crown... Great...!

Comment: {\'o}

{\'o}

Malformed UTF-8 character (unexpected end of string) in substitution (s///) at C:/Perl/site/lib/LaTeX/Encode.pm line 1

**Third one print this** -- >01.

Malformed UTF-8 character (fatal) at C:/Perl/site/lib/LaTeX/Encode.pm line 101.

Comment: @Mahe_sundar: It sounds like you haven't read and decoded your input string properly. You need to ask a new question and show your code and data.

Comment: Just I copied the above code and tried it in my windows machine. Hence I got this warn msg enough.

Comment: @Mahe_sundar: Do you have `use utf8` in place at the top?

Comment: Yes... full code copied from the above. My perl version `This is perl 5, version 18, subversion 4 (v5.18.4) built for MSWin32-x86-multi-thread-64int
(with 1 registered patch, see perl -V for more detail)`

Comment: @Mahe_sundar: Ill see if I can reproduce the problem when I get back to a PC. Can you check the versions of perl and of the modules, please?

Comment: Sure. I can check and let you know. Thanks.

Comment: @Mahe_sundar: Okay my guess is that, while your code contains `use utf8` to say that the source file UTF-8-encoded, it's actually in ISO-8859-1 or Windows-1252 or similar. You can either change your editor to use UTF-8, or you can use the `Encode` module to decode the non-ASCII strings in your program. On the other hand, if all your data is coming from an external source, then it will be sufficient just to decode that appropriately and everything should work.

Answer (score -2):

I needed about 2 hours to find my mistake. Perl did not detect my input string being coded in UTF-8.

You can help perl to treat the input string as utf-8
with:
use open ( ":encoding(UTF-8)", ":std" );