# How can I convert DB2 UTF-8 Czech special characters to LaTeX format?

Tags: perl, utf-8, db2, latex

I'm having trouble converting UTF-8 characters in a DB2 database to LaTeX format.

I have a DB2 database which is in codeset UTF-8 and codepage 1208. I have a field "lastname" that has some names that contain the East European special characters š ("s" with caron, Unicode code point U+0161, HTML entity `&#353;`) and á ("a" with acute, Unicode code point U+00E1, HTML entity `&#225;`).

My environment in the shell is LANG de_DE.utf8. I read the database field in Perl with the DBI module and want to convert the name to LaTeX format for printing, but it doesn't work for the character š.

I want to convert these characters as follows:

- `á` -> `\'{a}`
- `š` -> `\v{s}`

I'm able to convert á but not š with the following code (`$tmp` contains `áš`):

```
print TeX::Encode::encode('latex',$tmp);
```

This gives `\'a?`. `\'a` is correct but `?` for the š is not.

When I save the field directly to a file and look at it with a hex editor it shows `e1 1a`. `e1` is correct but `1a` isn't (according to Latin-2 it should be `b9`).

Can someone please help me convert these East European names from a UTF-8 database to a universal LaTeX format for printing?

Comment: [May be this will help you in part](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38587627/convert-non-ascii-utf-8-characters-into-latex-codes)

Comment: I suspect that you did not decode the database values to Perl strings before you tried to encode them to LaTeX. Try running: `perl -Mutf8 -mTeX::Encode -E '$tmp = "áš"; say TeX::Encode::encode("latex", $tmp )'`.